# Как вывести определенные данные с таблицы с отношением OneToMany?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Приветствую! Просьба помочь, есть две таблицы, в одной есть отношение по полю к другой OneToMany, при выводе работает все правильно, но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы из второй таблицы выводились не все записи которые соответствуют этому связанному полю, а только некоторые в которых есть соответствие с передаваемым значение из вне. 
К примеру есть запрос на сервер типа: htttp://myserver/get/new/{token}
он мне выдает все записи с одной таблицы и подтягивает к каждой записи соответствия с другой таблицы, а мне нужно чтобы он подтянул все эти записи только с тем токеном который я передал, поле токен в таблице есть.
Код первой сущности:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "news")
    public class News {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date newsDate;

        @Column(name = "summary", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String summary;

        @Column(name = "image_url", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String image_url;

        @Column(name = "category", nullable = false, length = 10000)
        private String category;

        @Column(name = "likeInt")
        private Long likeInt;

        @Column(name = "diz_likeInt")
        private Long diz_likeInt;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_news")
        private List<LikeOrDizlike> likeOrDizlike = new ArrayList<>(); 
+ геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

код второй сущности:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "LikeOrDizlike")
    public class LikeOrDizlike {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "id_news")
        private Long id_news;

        @Column(name = "token", nullable = false, length = 50)
        private String token;

        @Column(name = "onClickLike")
        private Boolean onClickLike;

        @Column(name = "onClickDizLike")
        private Boolean onClickDizLike;
+ геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

В проекте используется Spring-nibernate-JPA

Кастомные запрос описываю в интерфейсе унаследованном от JpaRepository.

Не совсем могу понять где и как реализовать такую логику, возможно ли это или нет?

Как мне получить в array list LikeOrDizlike только те записи которым соответствует токен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя стоит fetch = FetchType.EAGER ранняя инициализация то есть при загрузке entity news также будут запросы ко всем указанным в array list LikeOrDizlike. Не совсем понятен вопрос что хочешь получить?

Comment: Как сделать запрос сразу в две таблицы средствами - Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Как мне получить  в array list LikeOrDizlike только те записи которым соответствует токен?

Comment: Тебе нужно сделать запрос со spring data jpa к сущности LikeOrDizlike. Где в запросе указать выбрать все где токен равняется определенному токену. Чтобы сделать запрос в две таблищы можно сделать свой класс для spring data. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations